# get the id of a row

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
session_start();
include("configdb.php");
if(!session_is_registered(username)){
header("location:index.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Projects</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="modalPopLite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="modalPopLite.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
   $('#popup-wrapper').modalPopLite({ openButton: '#clicker', closeButton: '#close-btn' });
});
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["f1"]["project"].value;
  if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("all fileds are required");
  return false;
}
}


function Confirm(form){
alert("Project has been activated!"); 
form.submit();
}
function unConfirm(form){
alert("Project has been Deactivated!"); 
form.submit();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="costDiv">
<div id="divErc"></div>
<div id="costBack">

<?php

$sql="SELECT * FROM projects ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

?>
<?php include("hor_menu.php");?>

<div id="container"><br/><div id="clicker" style="cursor:pointer; width:120px;margin-left:15px;color:#20358c; font-weight:bold"">Add New Project</div>
<div id="popup-wrapper" style="background-color: #ccc; height:150px">
<form action="addnewproject.php" method="post" name="f1" onSubmit="return validateForm();">
<table>
<tr>
<td><label><h4>Project :</h4></label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="new_project" id="project" class="text-input-pop" /></td>
<tr>
<td><label><h4>Country :</h4></label></td>
<td><select name="country" id="country" style="width:190px ; height:31px"> 
    <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
    <option value="UAE">UAE</option>
</select> </td>
</tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="styled-button-4" style="margin-left:130px;"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form> 
<a id="close-btn" href="#">Close</a></div><table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" align="center" style="text-align:center">



<form name="frmactive" method="post" action="">

<table width="350" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" align="center" style="margin-left:150px ; margin-right:auto ; margin-top:20px ; margin-bottom:auto ; position:absolute ; width:400px">
<tr>
<td align="left"><strong>Project</strong></td>
<td align="left"><strong>Country</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Staus</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=" . $rows['p_id'] . " />"; echo $id;?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['p_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['p_country']; ?></td>
<td><?php if ($rows['p_isActive'] == '1'){  ?>
<input name="activate" type="submit" value="Activate" disabled="disabled"/>
<input name="deactivate" type="submit" value="Deactivate" />

<?php
} else{
?>  
<input name="activate" type="submit" id="activate" value="Activate" />
<input name="deactivate" type="submit" id="deactivate" value="Deactivate" disabled="disabled"/>
<?php
    }

    if(isset($_POST['activate'])){


    echo $rows['p_id'];

    $sql="UPDATE projects SET p_isActive = '1' WHERE p_id = '".$rows['p_id']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }


     ?>

</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

if i have this code.i want when clicking on activate to activate the row and the same for deactivate.how can i get the id of each row in order to update according to the id.thank you.i tried using hidden field but it's not working with me.i am new to this.thank you for your help

Comment: What have you tried yet except to find the source code above? How looks your database schema?

Comment: i have table called projects:its has p_id,p_name,p_isActive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set a variable with the $rows['p_id'] value. Try this:

```
    $activate = $rows['p_id'];

    $sql="UPDATE projects SET p_isActive = '1' WHERE p_id = '$activate'";
```

Comment: i tried it but it seems its not reading the id cz i tried to echo the query